# Generalization of Euclidean metric for density matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator

Is there a metric on density matrices that generalizes the Euclidean distance on pure states? Formally, I would like a metric $d$ on density matrices such that, in the special case where $\rho = | \psi \rangle\langle \psi|$ and $\rho' = | \psi' \rangle\langle \psi'|$, it holds that $d(\rho, \rho') = || \psi - \psi' ||$. (Alternately, is there a distance measure that generalizes the *squared* Euclidean distance?)